# Object Binding in Caliburn.Micro MVVM Framework with SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have the following Models:

```
public class Profile
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Member casemanager { get; set; }
        public Member assistant { get; set; }
    }

public class Member 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Type{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

In my ViewModel, I have the following objects:

- an `ObservableCollection<Profile>` named Profiles that gets populated from a database;
- a SelectedProfile of type Profile, of course;
- Two Lists of Members named ListCaseManagers and ListAssistants that get populated from DB.

Each of the objects implement a `NotifyOfPropertyChange` method from Caliburn.Micro and are set with property and backing field.

**The View:**

```
<StackPanel>
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Profiles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProfile}" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectionMode="Single" />
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListCaseManagers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProfile.casemanager }"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListAssistants}" SelectedItem="{Binding  SelectedProfile.assistant}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In this XAML I was thinking that the SelectedItem of each ComboBox would bind directly to the SelectedProfile casemanager/assistant, changing everytime I modify the SelectedProfile using the ListView, but it doesn't seem to select the item in the combobox even though SelectedProfile.casemanager and SelectedProfile.assistant are not null.

What am I missing? Is there an easy way using conventions with Caliburn.Micro?

Comment: There is a mistake. You are bind SelectedItem to SelectedProfile.. but in combobox SelectedItem binded to SelectedProfil. Check your output - you will see data binding exceptions.

Comment: @Anton actually it was an error from translation. The names are in a different language and, in the process of clearing irelevant code, I have translated the object names.

Comment: Also List binded to Profile. instead of mention property Profiles with type ObservableCollection<Profile>.. also possible reason can that you are using IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem.. which is means that you probably use some CollectionView as data source.. try remove this attribute if it not the case.

Comment: @Anton, also a translaton error. In past, I've put my code with foreign names and I have been advised no to do so, this is why I have tried to translate all the names :) I have removed IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In combobox present couple properties which can allow you to modify your SelectedItem in your list.

```
SelectedValuePath="Id" <br/>
SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedProfile.casemanager.Id}"
```

**Upd**: this approach allow to bind selected element by their some unique attribute (ID or Name)

In case if you need to work with SelectedItem.. you must sure that props of items in Profiles collection are related to object in ListCaseManagers and ListAssistants

```
var query = from p in Profiles
            join mgr in ListCaseManagers on p.casemanager==mgr
            select p;
? query.Count
enter code here
```

I assume you will see 0.. since objects in collection are different.

Comment: I have tried this, but without any success. I do not understand why do I need to put  SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue if my Source is a list of objects and I need a reference to the entire object, not just a value.

Comment: Probably you are trying to bind items from different collections.. which contains different instances.. This approach allow you to operate some unique values instead of refferences (if you are using SelectedItem)

Answer (score 1):

to use the convention name of Caliburn, you have to give a name to your control

for example for ListView:

```
<StackPanel>
 <ListView x:Name ="Profiles"  />
</StackPanel>
```

with the convention of names, Caliburn binds automatically the collection Profiles and use SelectedProfiles as SelectedItem

Answer (score 1):

You either need to raise the `PropertyChanged` for the `SelectedProfile` property when it's set:

```
private Profile_selectedProfile;
public ProfileSelectedProfile
{
    get { return _selectedProfile; }
    set
    {
        _selectedProfile = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedProfile);
    }
}
```

Or you could bind to the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListView` control itself:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView x:Name="lv" ItemsSource="{Binding Profiles}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProfile}" 
            DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectionMode="Single" />
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListCaseManagers}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem.casemanager, ElementName=lv }"  
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListAssistants}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem.assistant, ElementName=lv}" 
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: @MarianV.: Did you try this or what happened?

Comment: It did not work out this way, only with SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath and I still do not understand why. Even though ListCaseManager contains a list of Member and the SelectedItem.casemanager was set previously from the ListCaseManager, at load time, the item in the combobox is not selected. I am thinking that it is not enought that the object has the same properties, but instead it has to be from the same very instance. I don't know if I made myself clear. That is why using SelectedValue is more reliable because it selects the item based on a property.

Comment: @MarianV.: *I am thinking that it is not enought that the object has the same properties, but instead it has to be from the same very instance.* Yes, this is true. Unless you override the `Equals` method of the type.